# GDM login screen is not displayed with VNC

Tags: linux, vnc, xdmcp

I set up VNC server with xinetd.
Also configured GDM so that XDMCP is enabled.

VNC connection seems okay, but GDM login screen is not shown.
Instead I can only see old bare X screen (gray meshed background and X-shaped mouse pointer),
which I can't do any interaction with it.

What can I do to fix the problem?
No log is written below /var/log/.

Server distribution: Ubuntu marverick

/etc/xinetd.d/vnc is like below:

```
service vnc1024
{
  disable      = no
  socket_type  = stream
  protocol     = tcp
  wait         = no
  user         = nobody
  server       = /usr/bin/Xvnc
  server_args  = -inetd -query localhost -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24 -once securitytypes=none
  port         = 12345
}
```

/etc/gdm/custom.conf:

```
[daemon]
[security]
DisallowTCP=false
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
[gui]
[greeter]
[chooser]
[debug]
[servers]
```

/etc/services is also configured.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

GDM has problems with XDMCP. I had it working before upgrading to Lucid, but it is now broken.  I was unable to find a solution. I went with a split implementation using both XDM for XDMCP logins and GDM for my console.  My post on [Remote Desktops with VNC and RDP](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/) details how I made it work.  I have been using RDP most of the time as it handles different resolutions more easily.

Comment: Great article! It is really helpful. It worked with XDM. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Why not try using xdm or kdm instead?  I suspect old plain-vanilla xdm will likely work.